# Unable to use HTML 5 video timeline to scrub along video

Tags: html, amazon-s3, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am unable to load a HTML video element (from AWS S3) in webm format and use the timeline to scrub along it. The timeline works once the whole video has played once.

Is there a way of being able to use it from the start?

I can't tell if it is a problem server or client side.

Below is an example of the video and how it looks throughout the first play.

[image]

Comment: odd. unlike mp4 which requires faststart to move the metadata to the front, webm should already behave properly (though you might want to review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers#webm for current support and status of VP8 and VP9 codecs in different browsers)

Comment: So have done some more testing and Firefox works but Chrome just doesn't like it. I am starting to think the only option would be building bespoke controls.

Comment: have you tried re-encoding as mp4 with faststart? I've had more luck with that (or switch to DASH)